# In Confessions I.18, does Augustine clearly indicate the physical death of an enemy?

Tags: meaning, augustinus

In Augustine's [*Confessions*, I.18](http://faculty.georgetown.edu/jod/latinconf/1.html), he writes:

> et certe non est interior litterarum scientia quam scripta conscientia, id se alteri facere quod nolit pati. quam tu secretus es, habitans in excelsis in silentio, deus solus magnus, lege infatigabili spargens poenales caecitates supra inlicitas cupiditates, cum homo eloquentiae famam quaeritans ante hominem iudicem, circumstante hominum multitudine, inimicum suum odio inmanissimo insectans, vigilantissime cavet, ne per linguae errorem dicat: Inter omines, et ne per mentis furorem hominem auferat ex hominibus non cavet.

The key phrase for my question is translated by [Henry Chadwick](https://books.google.com/books?id=1QkigkuD_3oC&pg=PA21) as follows:

> [The speaker] is indifferent to the possibility that the emotional force of his mind **may bring about a man's execution**.

The same portion is translated a bit differently by [Edward Pusey](http://www.sacred-texts.com/chr/augconf/aug01.htm):

> [He] takes no heed, lest, through the fury of his spirit, **he murder the real human being**.

Note the difference between "bring about a man's execution" and "murder the real human being."  This may seem inconsequential, but in Christianity, there's a teaching that hatred or anger is akin to murder (see [Matthew 5:21–22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matthew%205%3A21-22&version=ESV;VULGATE)), which could theoretically allow Pusey's translation to be read as "he *sin against* the real human being" or "he murder the real human being *in his heart*."

My question, thus, revolves around this distinction:

- Does the Latin text specifically indicate, or strongly imply, capital punishment as the outcome of the speaker's eloquence?
- Is the *physical death* of the man clearly indicated?
- Or is a metaphorical interpretation possible or likely?

---

<sup>This question is inspired by an answer to a [question regarding Augustine's views on capital punishment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/47118/21576).  If Chadwick unjustifiably makes the connection to capital punishment, perhaps this passage tells us nothing about Augustine's view of the practice.</sup>

Comment: Is *hominem ex hominibus auferre* a common expression in Christian Latin? I have never seen it, and understanding its connotations seems important here.

Comment: Words meaning *remove* often mean "kill" in Latin, like *tollo*. Lewis & Short say *aufero* is synonymous with *tollo* and a few similar words. They also offer "kill" as a subsense. So I think the connotation of murder is probably present—or at least it would be in classical Latin.

Comment: (Caveat: Long time since I read the Confessions.) Isn't the context of this passage more about the wrongheadedness of  worrying about making grammatical errors by speaking incorrectly (as, say, a rhetorician would, or an orator) even though the force of the words may be meant to convict someone who faced the death penalty. That is, Augustine suggests that worrying about what the words are used for is more important than worrying about using them in a grammatically correct fashion. I think I prefer Chadwick because it captures the idea that the speaker's words may bring about the execution.

Comment: See also O'Donnell's summary of this portion of the *Confessions* ([1.18.29](http://faculty.georgetown.edu/jod/conf/comm1.html)): 'Two patterns of order are superimposed on each other here, with their similarities drawn out to contrast the values they represent. Order and law exist in human language as it is used here, but it is all shown to be a fraud, and a killing one at that, by the hidden order and law of God that works in and through even the deeds of his most perverse opponents.'